# Storing beauty dishes?

Tags: equipment-storage, beauty-dish

I have a number of beauty dishes (ranging from 20.5-22.5” diameter and 8-9” depth) and due to the counter reflectors they obviously don’t nest well like other reflectors.  Has anyone come up with a clever storage solution that doesn’t involve some ungodly expensive aftermarket case.  Drum cases were about the best I could come up with.

Comment: Do they make hat boxes sturdy enough?

Comment: That’s a thought, though those can be quite pricey as well.  Perhaps there’s a deep wreath storage box someone makes.

Answer (score 1):

For smaller beauty dishes up to about 12 inches in diameter, I've been known to use a ['cake caddy'](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B0000CF8Q6) once or twice. But I'm not sure if you can easily find them in sizes of 24+ inches.